# How to interpolate subsurface geology from borehole data

Tags: arcgis-desktop, interpolation, geology, subsurface, borehole

I have borehole data (x, y, z values for each subsurface measurement, and its associated lithology). I would like to interpolate the borehole data to create 1) interpolated subsurfaces and 2) lithological profiles at specific cross-sections. I only have access to the ArcGiS package w/ extensions, but no other software packages, nor the budget to access them.

I need to know if the above is possible with the tools and data that I have, and if so, what tools and methodology I should be looking into.

Comment: See [Creating Faulted Geologic Surfaces with ArcGIS](http://www.esri.com/esri-news/arcuser/summer-2014/creating-faulted-geologic-surfaces-with-arcgis).  I think it assumes the faults are vertical, as well as the boreholes.  Are your depths True Vertical Depth Subsea (TVDSS)?

Comment: Thanks, I just saw this now and will look into it. I actually have no idea how the depths were measured. A lot of this data is old, and there is little indication of how they measured it, which I understand could be a big problem when it comes to accuracy.

Comment: If the data is [lithology logs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well_logging), treating lithologic breaks as [surfaces/layer boundaries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horizon_(geology)) can be *very* unreliable.

Answer (score 1):

I would have suggested using the Spatial Analyst extension to get at the same, but since you mentioned that you have access to only the above resources, I suggest using the Raster Interpolation Toolset, which comes with the 3D analyst extension. 
There are different approaches, depending on the result you seek. I suggest checking the Kriging or the Natural Neighbour option as they seem to be very effective at interpolation for what you are asking.

Comment: Sorry, I do have spatial analyst, all the extensions. I meant I only have ArcGIS, nothing more.

Comment: If you have the Geostatistical Analyst extension available, I think this can achieve what you are needing.

Comment: I have this. Can you clarify for which step I would need this? Interpolation of points?

Comment: Search for the Raster Interpolation Toolset within ArcGIS. That will work with the extension you presently have.